# HTTP POST with JSON object returned c#

Tags: c#, json, http, http-post

I am trying to create a HTTP Post that returns a JSON object with 2 attributes.

Details are below:

HTTP POST to http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/ with form encoded data which contains a string. A JSON object response with 2 attributes is retuned; lable and negative.

I am tying to do this in c#, which is where I am struggling.

Thank you

Comment: Not a lot I have been reading up on it but do not know where to start, I know not the best way to do this, but I didnt know what else to do, I am unsure how even to do a HTTP Post request with a string value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using a `WebClient` like this

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection postValues = new NameValueCollection();
postValues.Add("foo", "fooValue");
postValues.Add("bar", "barValue");
byte[] responseArray = webclient.UploadValues(*url*, postValues);
string returnValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
```

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) also has an example.

Comment: I tired this but how do I collect the returned Json value?

Comment: @user the MSDN example is doing that. I'll edit my answer to cover that.